# $E(Z_1^2|Z_1+Z_2=s)$ where $Z_1,Z_2$ are iid. normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm looking for the fastest way to compute the conditional expectation. I'm mostly stuck with $E(Z_1Z_2|Z_1+Z_2=s)$. I'm not sure if $E(Z_1Z_2|Z_1+Z_2=s)=E(Z_1|Z_1+Z_2=s)E(Z_2|Z_1+Z_2=s)$. Any ideas except for brute force calculus would be helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to compute $E[Z_1^2|Z_1+Z_2]$? Since $P[Z_1+Z_2 = s] = 0$, the traditional conditional probability is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slick derivation that avoids brute force. Hints:

(1) By symmetry, $E(Z_1^2\mid Z_1+Z_2)=E(Z_2^2\mid Z_1+Z_2)$.

(2) Consider the identity
$u^2+v^2=\frac12(u-v)^2 + \frac12(u+v)^2.
$

(3) Prove, then use, the fact that $Z_1 + Z_2$ is independent of $Z_1 - Z_2$.

Comment: If $Z_1+Z_2 = s$ then $Z_1,Z_2$ are not independent.

Answer (score 0):

The event $Z_1+Z_2=s$ is null, so you are conditioning on a null event, which by convention is defined to be $0$.

If you want $\mathbb{E}[Z_1^2\mid Z_1+Z_2]$ instead, then do not write it as $\mathbb{E}[Z_1^2\mid Z_1+Z_2=s]$, and use the rotation as in grand_chat's solution.